# Setting visiblity to section of data template in a listview

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF/MVVM application. When a item is selected in my listview I have a section of the datatemplate I want to be visible, then when a different item is selected it will be collapsed, and the new item will be visible. I will mock up some code below to help show what I am trying to do.

My question is how to do this for just the selected item staying in the bounds of mvvm. I know I can bind to a property in my viewmodel, but if every item has the same binding they all open, I need it to be for just the selected item and I'm not sure the best way to deal with this in MVVM, looking for suggestions. The item source in my listview is a ObservableCollection of a class that stores some default data I need when the item is selected.

```
            <ListView Name="lvMain"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemSource, Mode=TwoWay}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding MyPath, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <!-- removing the rest to keep this short -->
                </Grid>
                <!-- This section below is collapsed by default, when selected I'd like to set the visibility, my question is how to only set the visibility in the grid below when the item is selected -->
                <Grid Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding ??}">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <!-- removing the rest to keep this short -->
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll need some boolean to visibility converter but you can use built in one if you don't have yours and then you need to use `RelativeSource` binding to go up the visual tree, find `ListViewItem` and bind to its `IsSelected` property via that converter

```
<ListView Name="lvMain" ...>
    <ListView.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- removed content -->
            <Grid 
                ...
                Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, 
                    Path=IsSelected, 
                    Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks, did exactly what I wanted. Appreciate the help.